# is it possible to grab and move child bone and make parent's rotation follow it?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

i'm trying to make it so that child bone can be grabbed and moved in Pose Mode while being connected to the parent bone, while parent bone rotates to face it's child and doesn't stretch. imagine a neck and head bone, where head always faces forward, but neck rocks the head back and forth.

i can do something similar by disabling "Inherit Rotation" on a child and then rotating the parent; also, something similar could be done with IK, but it requires extra bone or two.

Comment: What you described is basically an IK chain.  Am I missing something?  I suspect you also want FK manipulation mixed in, but the question is unclear.

Comment: yes, it is basically an IK chain, BUT the child with IK constraint will also be pointing it's end towards IK target. i want to be able to rotate the child individually, so it won't depend on anything else.

Comment: i mean NORMALLY the child would be pointing towards IK target, but i don't need that. i was trying to make it so that the child would keep it's initial rotation no matter where it gets moved, so it could be rotated as any usual object.

i could turn the child into IK target, but then it will be disconnected from ex-parent and i need it to be connected.

Comment: you are self contradicting: " the child with IK constraint will also be pointing it's end towards IK target" followed immediately with "i want to be able to rotate the child individually".   You can't have both. The follow up comment makes no sense.   You might want to take a step back and think about what you really want

Comment: I recommend re-wording your question to state your goal, and strip out your guesses and speculation

Comment: "the child with IK constraint will also be pointing it's end towards IK target"  - i mean that's what would normally happen, i don't need that.